# Network and FTP issues

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, netplan

I am new to Ubuntu. I've done installs on CentOS and Redhat, but on Ubuntu I am having network and ftp issues. I ask them together as these issues might be related.

This is also my first experience with netplan.

I did the install and had no issues. Then I installed vsftpd and it works when I use it using localhost on the server, but not from any other system in my network. Initially, I thought that the default ip address might be incompatible so I changed the address to something in my domain, but vsftpd still is not visible and I no longer have internet access. my vsftpd.conf file is pretty much default.

My netplan yaml file looks like

```
network:
     version: 2
     ethernets:
          ens33:
              addresses: [192.168.0.201/24]
              gateway4: 192.168.0.1
              nameservers:
                  addresses: [75.75.75.75,192.168.0.145]
```

The DNS servers are one provided by my ISP and the other is a local server

My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 which runs on a VMWare virtual machine

Do I have two issues here, or one networking issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Some additional information. I'm using FileZilla as an FTP client. The version of Ubuntu is the community server edition. I can ping the server from other systems in my network.

Comment: Mind sharing your vsftpd configuration?  It would be important to have that as well.

Comment: Netplan is very picky about indentation. Is the above what your yaml file actually reads?

Comment: When I issue netplan apply I get no errors. After changing the ip address I can ping the server using ping 192.168.0.201. So I assume it's working, however, I no longer have internet access. ifconfig shows the changes were made.

Comment: vsftpd.conf looks like this (I removed comments for clarity in this post)  listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO